# Laravel Nova add breakline in computed output

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

So currently I'm using Laravel nova to create like a dashboard where you see all the necessary without having the needs to click on the detail page. Currently the data that I would like to show is a shipping address. With computed you can get multiply values on one field, now I would like to add a breakline so that you have something like the following

John Doe
Street 34
City ..

*How to achieve this, without having to break all the security implemented by the Nova stuff..*

**Computed function**

```
Text::make('Shipping address', function () {
    return 'firstname <br> lastname';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The computed content of the field is rendered here:

```
<!-- nova/resources/js/components/PanelItem.vue:12 -->

<p v-if="field.value" class="text-90">{{ field.value }}</p>
```

As you can see, the html is escaped. Therefore, you cannot use the `<br>`. However, you can use it with the `Textarea` field.

```
Textarea::make('Shipping address', function () {
    return 'firstname <br> lastname';
});
```

But note that this will show a clickable **Show Content** (excerpt) before showing the actual content.